# Reduction of order to find a second Frobenius solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$xy''-y=0$ and $y_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!(n-1)!}$ so via reduction of order:$$y_2=Cy_1\ln(x)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$$I've substituted $y_2$ into the ODE and got the recurrence relation:$$n(n+1)b_{n+1}-b_n=-C(\frac{2n+1}{n!(n+1)!})$$however I can't get the right substitution in the form $b_n=f(n)*c_n$ (where $f(n)$ is a term involving n and possibly C) to simplify the recurrence relation and then solve for $y_2$. I've tried multiple substitutions and they all end up dividing by $0$ meaning that my recurrence relation cannot be in terms of $b_0$ or $c_0$. Can someone please explain the algorithm for identifying the substitution that simplifies the recurrence relation?

Answer (score 0):

Besides getting that recursion, you should look at the constants: when you write $xy_2''-y_2=0$, the constant term is $C-b_0$. So $C=b_0$. So
$$
b_{n+1}=\frac{b_n}{n(n+1)}-\frac{(2n+1)b_0}{n!(n+1)!}.
$$

Comment: How do you mean? I got the constant term to be C(2*(y1')-(y1)/x) (the RHS of the recurrence relation).